# Issue with REPLACE in SQL

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I am trying to replace multiple words in a string in SQL using the replace.

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(wholeString,'{{Name}}',w.Name),'{{ID}}',w.ID),'{{Sal}}',@salary) AS DETAILS
```

The replacement values are read from another table aliased as w.

When I execute the PROC from SSMS the "DETAILS" get inserted into the required table. But when I run the proc from the code, blank is inserted in the table.

The code only passes an ID which is correctly received at the SP end as I tested by printing it out.

Also,Is there an alternative for replace?

Comment: Your query should be fine.  You should edit your question and provide sample data and show how the query does *not* work.

Comment: What do you mean "is there a alternative to `REPLACE`"? `REPLACE` performs a very simple function, it finds **all** occurrences of a pattern within a string, and replaces **all** of those patterns with the 3rd parameter. The only time `REPLACE` will return `NULL` is if the value of any of the 3 parameters is also `NULL`. If `REPLACE` dose not find a pattern to replace it will still return the original value. `REPLACE('123','456','789')` returns `'123'`.

Comment: My query is mostly around the 2nd part of my question. Although the params are passed right and although the execution enters the if loop and inserts the required row in the new table in both scenarios (when run from ssms , when run from code) , blank is entered for "details" when the proc is called from code and works fine otherwise.

Comment: If you check your data you may find an issue.  I came across a similar problem where my data had some nulls in it, and replace with null, nulled the entire string, rather than replacing with a blank..  Took me a while to track mine down.

Comment: @Matthew , what did you do to check nulls before replace?

Comment: How does `@salary` get populated?

Comment: @Richard - It is a param along with ID and does get passed to SP.

Comment: The code above doesn't indicate the ID is a parameter.  It appears to be pulling from a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NB: Checking for nulls as per comment above.

```
SELECT  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(wholeString, '{{Name}}', ISNULL(w.Name,'')), '{{ID}}', ISNULL(w.ID,'')), '{{Sal}}', ISNULL(@salary,'')) AS DETAILS;
```

Please note as well that these columns you are pulling from need to be in a char format.  If a field like ID or the salary parameter are numeric you'll need to wrap that with a cast like:

```
ISNULL(CAST(w.ID as NVARCHAR(255)),'')
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try this instead?

`REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ISNULL(wholeString, 'NULLWHOLESTRING'),'{{Name}}',ISNULL(w.Name, 'NULLNAME')),'{{ID}}',ISNULL(w.ID, 'NULLID')),'{{Sal}}',ISNULL(@salary, 'NULLSALARY')) AS DETAILS`

That should give you an idea if the problem is caused by `NULL`s or not?

Comment: Yes, Null is the issue. I checked with replacing one of the values with null. Returned empty string.